# Vagrant Ubuntu server loses connectivity after host Ubuntu goes to sleep

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

**The issue is self explanatory:**

In Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop as a host, Ubuntu server 14.04LTS loses connectivity after host goes to sleep mode and repairs only after reload.

I've tried:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

none of these work.

How can I keep the connection working after sleep ?